# View 1-D object array like a 1-D struct array in variable editor

Tags: matlab, oop, struct

If I open up a 1-D object array in the variable editor I get an inconvenient view because I can't see property values of each object without clicking into each one individually.

```matlab
classdef myClass
    properties
        Property1 = 'abc'
        Property2 = 123
        Property3 = 'def'
    end
    
    methods
        function s = struct(self)
            pub_prop = properties(self);
            s(numel(self)) = struct;
            for iProp = 1:numel(pub_prop)
                [s.(pub_prop{iProp})] = self.(pub_prop{iProp});
            end
        end
    end
end
```

```matlab
objArray(4) = myClass;
```

Opening it up in variable editor  I see:

[image: Object array in variable editor]

I've defined a method to convert a 1-D object array to a 1-D struct array. Then with a struct array, I can see all property values at once, which is what I want.

```matlab
structArray = objArray.struct
```

Opening it up in variable editor  I see:

[image: Struct array in variable editor]

If I overload the `openvar` function, I can achieve what I want by converting to a struct array then passing it to `openvar`.

```matlab
classdef myClass2 < myClass
    properties

    end
    
    methods
        function openvar(varargin)
            s = inputname(1);
            openvar([s '.struct']);
        end
    end
end
```

```matlab
objArray2(4) = myClass2;
objArray2.openvar
```

But this doesn't work when I try to open up `objArray2` by double-clicking in Workspace. I get the error:

```matlab
Error using matlab.desktop.vareditor.VariableEditor.checkVariableName
The first argument to VariableEditor must be a valid variable name.

Error in openvar (line 96)
    matlab.desktop.vareditor.VariableEditor.checkVariableName(name);

Error in myClass2/openvar (line 9)
            openvar([s '.struct']);
```

**EDIT** My answer below works when I double-click the object array directly from Workspace, but it doesn't work if the object array is stored in another object or struct. Opening the struct below in variable editor, then the object array uses the default behavior of `openvar` with object arrays. Any ideas?

```
myStruct.objArray2b = objArray2b;
```

Interestingly, the struct array view works if the object array is double-clicked from within a cell.

Comment: You know, the `struct` method works on custom classes by default, you don’t need to overload it.

Comment: I think `struct` will only work with scalar objects and only converts the first object.

Comment: Something like `structArray = arrayfun(@struct, objArray)` is an option, but I wanted something to not get the object to struct warning messages

Answer (score 0):

The error message from calling the question's `myClass2.openvar` is because of how double-clicking from Workspace calls `openvar`. I'm not sure about the exact details of the interaction between `openvar` and Workspace, but `inputname(1)` evaluates to nothing. So then `openvar([s '.struct']);` is trying to open a variable named `.struct` which is an invalid name.

Looking at the function arguments of `openvar.m`, it looks like `varargin{1}` when called from double-clicking Workspace should be the variable name as a `char`. So the `myClass2.openvar` can be modified with branching behavior depending on the type of `varargin{1}`.

```matlab
classdef myClass2b < myClass
    properties

    end
    
    methods
        function openvar(varargin)
            if isa(varargin{1},'myClass2b')
                s = inputname(1);
                openvar([s '.struct']);
            elseif isa(varargin{1},'char') || isa(varargin{1},'string')
                openvar([varargin{1} '.struct']);
            else
                error('Unexpected error');
            end
        end
    end
end
```

```matlab
objArray2(4) = myClass2b;
```

Now double-clicking from Workspace works to display the object array as a 1-D struct array. And any of the below methods also works.

```
objArray2b.openvar
openvar(objArray2b)
openvar('objArray2b.struct')
```